# Missing library for JSON and RESTful in Glassfish

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

After re-installed Netbeans 7.4 with a fresh Glassfish 4.0, I got missing and conflicting libraries. I am using Jackson library for working with JSON and I need Jersey (from what I remember) to work with RESTful (client).

If I include the Jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS RI) library in Netbeans I get a conflict with the default JPA persistence library (`CascadeType` and `TypedQuery`). But it includes `JsonNode` and the `ObjectMapper` classes.

These are the classes that causes my problem;

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

I also noticed that I can set the full JEE 7 profile (only web) in the project settings for Netbeans. I think this was available before in prevous versions of Netbeans.

What libraries (version) do I need to include (I don't use Maven) to solve my JSON/RESTful problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of including the default Jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS RI) library in Netbeans, which causing the conflict with the JPA persistence library. I've downloaded and included these specific libraries to handle the JSON parsing and mapping;

```
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2
```

I've downloaded the libs from [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse)

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish already has JAX-RS libraries, so you don't need to add any JARs to your project except the Glassfish Runtime Libraries.

In Eclipse, check if you configured the Glassfish Runtime Library and if your project is assigned to use it. Also, check if you activated the Project Facet of JAX-RS. All this can be done on Properties menu of the project.

Comment: I am using Netbeans and the JAX-RS don't have JsonNode, ObjectMapper classes.

Comment: Jersey comes with Jackson already. Also, if your service is simple, you don't need to use Jackson directly. Check this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: ALso, I think ObjectMapper from Jackson is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper. See: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/

Comment: Hi, when included the default JAX-RS, I've got the conflict with the JPA persistence (Eclipse-link). So I only included the Jackson libraries that that was missing in the Glassfish.